# NavigationService missing definition in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am implementing a **WPF** application where I navigate from one window(**ListScreen.xaml**) to another window(**PlayerWindow.xaml**). I'm using NavigationService for the same.

I want the navigation to happen on the click of a button hence the following code for a button in ListScreen.xaml:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            Uri uri = new Uri("PlayerWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative); //Line 1
            NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this); //Line 2
            ns.NavigationService.Navigate(uri); //Line 3
}
```

I've added `using System.Windows.Navigation;`.

But Line 3 of the code gives the following error:

```
Error   324 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService' and no extension method 'NavigationService' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'
```

Any help as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Why not you using `Show` function. Is navigation is necessary in wpf applications ??

Comment: Yes navigation is necessary

Comment: I get the error <<'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService' is a type not a namespace>> when using this....

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ns.NavigationService.Navigate(uri); //Line 3
```

with

```
ns.Navigate(uri);
```

---

**Edit**: please note the Remarks section in [GetNavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice.aspx):

> GetNavigationService returns null when the dependencyObject:
>
> • Is a NavigationWindow.
>
> • Is a Frame that:
>
> 1. Is hosted by another navigator.
> 2. Has its JournalOwnership property set to UsesParentJournal.
>
> • Is not part of content that is hosted by a navigator.

Comment: On making this change the code compiled..but ns.navigate(uri); gives a NullReferenceException when the button is clicked.

Comment: The project has only two xaml's - ListScreen and PlayerWindow. Do I need to change any properties of the windows to make navigation possible?

Comment: I guess they should be Pages, not Windows.

Comment: Their Build Action property is set to 'Page' only.

Comment: I meant they should be derived from class Page, not Window. Please take a look at the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) article on MSDN.